# how to combine NSLayout Constraints with CGrect frame (Swift4)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4, nslayoutconstraint, cgrect

I am trying to create a textfield pragmatically, using no storyboard. My current code is having a compile error. I need to use NSLayout constraint to make sure my code can work on both a ipad and iphone.

```
    import UIKit
var aa:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var btn : UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btn = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))

    let leadingc2 = btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
    let trailingC2 = btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    let topc2 = btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: -50)
    let bottomc2 = btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250)

    aa = [leadingc2,trailingC2,topc2,bottomc2]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(aa)
    self.view.addSubview(btn)
}


}
```

Comment: You said “ My current code is having a compile error.” Please copy the error, edit your question, and paste in the error.

Comment: THIS IS COMING FROM MY LOG FILE:2018-08-24 22:17:19.377011-0400 new[13239:626463] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000470e80 "UITextField:0x7f9be803a200.centerX"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000470f80 "UIView:0x7f9be7c0c1f0.centerX"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

Comment: That is not a compile error. That is a runtime error.

Comment: because you have to set the constraint to self.view to its superview.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh  self.view.didAddSubview(btn) does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try rewriting these two lines in this order:

```
view.addSubview(btn)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(aa)
```

Constraints may not be applied to views that don't share a hierarchy, which means you cannot activate the constraints between the button and its superview until the button is added to that superview.

Comment: Does it change the output? Because it certainly addresses the problem that your error message is describing: you must put `btn` in `self.view`'s view hierarchy before you can activate constraints between `btn` and `self.view`.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your current error? You may not be seeing the results you expect, but you should no longer be receiving your former error. One additional requirement is to set `btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in order to prevent "frame-derived" constraints from conflicting with the ones you've defined.

Comment: @woodcutting I added your suggested code and I am getting a new error under   btn = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50)). Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I’m not sure what the state of your code is at this point, but that’s an exception you’d see in the event an Optional has been explicitly unwrapped before it was initialized. My suggestion is to avoid using implicitly unwrapped optionals whenever possible.